# ksh - Using a variable inside command substitution mechanism

Tags: bash, shell, sqlplus, ksh, heredoc

I am new to scripting in Linux and I think I'm getting confused with using variables inside command substitution the more I learn and read about it. Can someone explain to me the following scenario?

In my ksh script, I am trying to use a ksh variable inside an sqlplus script as follows:

```
temp_var="'a', 'b'" 
randomVar=$(sqlplus -s $con_details <<EOF

update table ABC 
Set field1='val' 
Where field2 NOT IN ("${temp_var}");
EOF)
```

But the above syntax leads to an error in the query and it fails with code 1.

However when I unquote the variable and simply write

```
Where field2 NOT IN (${temp_var});
```

The query runs fine. I have seen a lot of examples on SO and Unix and Linux advising to always quote your variables used inside command substitution, but it seems the opposite works for me.

I don't seem to get why using quotes inside $() give an error as opposed to not using them.

Also, the query runs fine when I don't use the ksh variable in it (i.e. Without the WHERE clause).

Comment: Do you use bash or ksh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a different situation than where the usual advice applies -- you're using the variable in a here-document, rather than as part of the command line. The difference is in how it gets parsed.

When you use a variable on a command line (something like `ls $file`), the variable gets replaced by its value partway through the process of parsing the command, with weird and generally undesirable results. The standard solution is to double-quote the variable (`ls "$file"`) to prevent it from being parsed at all, just used directly. The standard mistake people make is putting quotes in the variable's value, which doesn't work because the variable gets replaced *after* quotes have already been parsed.

But you're using the variable in a here-document, and those work a lot differently. What happens is that the shell just does variable expansion (and some escape parsing) in the here-document, but doesn't do any more extensive parsing. In particular, it doesn't parse quotes in the here-document, just treats them like any other characters. The document then gets passed as input to the command (`sqlplus` in your case), and *it* parses the document according to whatever its syntax rules are. Since the parsing happens after variable replacement, it doesn't matter if the quotes are in the variable or around it; they work the same either way. But you can't do both, which is what was happening with double-quotes around the variable. Essentially, you were sending this document to `sqlplus`:

```
update table ABC 
Set field1='val' 
Where field2 NOT IN ("'a', 'b'");
```

... and `sqlplus` doesn't like that double-quotes around single-quotes thing, and complains.